# Fill DataFrame using np.where with group by conditon

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a sample df:

```
id           email1       email2            output
 1       abc@gmail.com    123@gmail.com   random_email1@gmail.com
 1       xyz@gmail.com    234@gmail.com   random_email1@gmail.com
 1            NaN          NaN            random_email1@gmail.com
 2       a123@gmail.com    NaN            random_email2@gmail.com
 2       b123@gmail.com    NaN            random_email2@gmail.com
 2           NaN          lol@gmail.com   random_email2@gmail.com
 3           NaN           NaN            random_email3@gmail.com
 4           NaN          lolz@gmail.com   random_email3@gmail.com
```

My main goal is to overwrite the `output` column based on multiple conditions. If `email1` has more than one unique email, overwrite all the output with the corresponding IDs with `email1_broken`. Same goes for `email2` but if both have more than one unique email, `email2` takes priority and therefore `output = email2_broken`. Lastly, we retain the email in the current `output` column if both columns have an id with one unique email.

Attempt:

```
df['output'] = np.where(df.groupby('id')['email1'].nunique() > 1, 'email1_broken',df['output'])

df['output'] = np.where(df.groupby('id')['email2'].nunique() > 1, 'email2_broken',df['output'])
```

Desired df:

```
id           email1       email2            output
 1       abc@gmail.com    123@gmail.com   email2_broken
 1       xyz@gmail.com    234@gmail.com   email2_broken
 1            NaN          NaN            email2_broken
 2       a123@gmail.com    NaN            email1_broken
 2       b123@gmail.com    NaN            email1_broken
 2           NaN          lol@gmail.com   email1_broken
 3           NaN           NaN            random_email3@gmail.com
 4           NaN          lolz@gmail.com  random_email3@gmail.com
```

Sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cols = ['id','email1','email2', 'output']

data = [
[1   ,  'abc@gmail.com' ,   '123@gmail.com'    , 'random_email1@gmail.com'],
[1   ,  'xyz@gmail.com'  ,  '234@gmail.com'    , 'random_email1@gmail.com'],
[1   ,      np.nan      ,      np.nan          , 'random_email1@gmail.com'],
[2   ,   'a123@gmail.com',     np.nan          , 'random_email2@gmail.com'],
[2   ,   'b123@gmail.com',     np.nan          , 'random_email2@gmail.com'],
[2   ,     np.nan        ,   'lol@gmail.com'   , 'random_email2@gmail.com'],
[3   ,     np.nan        ,     np.nan          , 'random_email3@gmail.com'],
[4   ,     np.nan        ,   'lolz@gmail.com'  , 'random_email3@gmail.com']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close:

```
df['output'] = np.where(df.groupby('id')['email1'].transform('nunique') > 1, 'email1_broken',df['output'])
df['output'] = np.where(df.groupby('id')['email2'].transform('nunique') > 1, 'email2_broken',df['output'])
```

Use transform to obtain the boolean array with the same shape.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.select` (the equivalent of `numpy.where` when multiple conditions are involved) with `transform('nunique')`:

```
g = df.groupby('id')

df['output'] = np.select(
 [g['email2'].transform('nunique').gt(1),
  g['email1'].transform('nunique').gt(1)],
 ['email2_broken', 'email1_broken'],
 df['output'])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  id          email1          email2                   output
0   1   abc@gmail.com   123@gmail.com            email2_broken
1   1   xyz@gmail.com   234@gmail.com            email2_broken
2   1             NaN             NaN            email2_broken
3   2  a123@gmail.com             NaN            email1_broken
4   2  b123@gmail.com             NaN            email1_broken
5   2             NaN   lol@gmail.com            email1_broken
6   3             NaN             NaN  random_email3@gmail.com
7   4             NaN  lolz@gmail.com  random_email3@gmail.com
```